# Javascript variable not changing inside onload function

Tags: javascript, filereader

this code always return me '3' in alert.

I select two files together (ones `.mp4` format and second ones `.zip` format)

```js
    function readFile(input) {
        var counter = input.files.length;
        for(x = 0; x<counter; x++){
            if (input.files && input.files[x]) {
                var extension = input.files[x].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    urlss = 1;
                    if(extension == 'mp4'){
                        urlss = 2;
                    }else{
                        urlss = 3;
                    }
                    alert(urlss);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[x]);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .zip, .mp4" onchange="readFile(this);" multiple />
```

Comment: I assume `urlss = '"2.jpg";` is a typo in the question?

Comment: You can return array

Comment: can you please add the full relevant code....

Comment: @AbhisarTripathi this is full code. it read files form an input file.

Comment: @icecub that was a misspelling.

Comment: whats the output when you add `console.log(extension);` before `urlss = 3`?

Comment: @aliali what I meant was adding full code using what we can test, using this code I can't upload a files and  figure out what is wrong....

Comment: @Webber before `reader.onload` it return true value, but in  `reader.onload`  always return last file extentions

Comment: @Abhisar Tripathi please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

The `onload` function calling after the for was ended and extension == `last file extension`

Try replace var with const:

```
function readFile(input) {
    var counter = input.files.length;
    for(let x = 0; x < counter; x++){
        if (input.files && input.files[x]) {
            const extension = input.files[x].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                urlss = 1;
                if(extension == 'mp4'){
                    urlss = 2;
                }else{
                    urlss = 3;
                }
                alert(urlss);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Please check the Webber's comment below.

Comment: So the real problem actually was that the reader.onload gets overridden in every iteration. It would be better if you define 1 FileReader, that has one `onload` function, and run `readAsDataURl` once per iteration on that single file reader. This answer creates a separate file reader for every file that is read.